# Limitations with Visual Studio Preview?

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio Preview and it works fine but recently I saw this in [their release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#16.7.0-pre.3.1) and it says

> This release is not "go-live" and not intended for use on production
> computers or for creating production code. For instructions on
> installing and updating Visual Studio 2019, see this documentation on
> updating Visual Studio 2019 to the most recent release.

so if I want to write production code do I need to install another stable version too(it takes more space)? and I'm happy with this version cause it's cool and sometimes can try preview versions of new technologies/frameworks.

and What I'm not able to do exactly with this preview version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not having the "go-live" just means that Microsoft is not guaranteeing support if used in production environments, because it contains pre-release/beta features and/or libraries.  Meaning if you deploy production code from a non "go-live" preview version of VS, you're on your own and can't call Microsoft for support/issues.

Occasionally, Microsoft will issue a "go-live" preview version (particularly with Release Candidates) that they will support.